# w2k8 AD recover dns data from demoted domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

Someone tried to replace their two win 2003 DCs with two new win 2008 DCs by replacing them one at a time (demoted win 2003 DC2 and replaced with 2008 DC2, then demoted 2003 DC1 and replaced it with 2008 DC).

Everything looked just fine, until their users started to report DNS failures; AFAIK the DNS records did not propagate from old DCs to the new ones.

At the moment they are recreating DNS records one by one as the users report the failures, but I was wondering if there is a way to recover the DNS data from one of the demoted DCs.

Are there any files they could try to recover and get a list of all the old DNS records?

Off course, no backup was made before replacing the DCs.

Comment: Were the zones AD integrated?

Comment: Yes, they were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, the DNS server files were located in %systemroot%\system32\dns on Windows Server 2003.

If you open up the backup folder, it should contain a copy of the existing DNS.  You most likely could edit it a bit and then import it..

Comment: Fortunately there was a very old backup image, found the dns zones in that directory. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad that worked.  I think at some point I needed it too...